# R: Reproducing a 3d plot with rockchalk or rgl

Tags: r, plot, 3d, rgl

I would like to make a 3d plot as the ones in figure 1 of this paper: Macher, JN., et al.: "Multiple-stressor effects on stream invertebrates: DNA barcoding reveals contrasting responses of cryptic mayfly species." Ecological Indicators 61 (2016): 159-169.

The authors did not give any details on the R package they used, but it looks like rockchalk or rgl. I have tried several things, but cannot get the 3d plane as in the figure. Can someone help with a script? [Figure 1 from Macher et al. 2016](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtCnZ.png)

Comment: Feel free to share what you tried so others can build up on that. If you do, make it a minimal reproducible example - ready to copy-paste-run in R out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think those were produced in `rgl`, but this produces something similar:

```
library(rgl)
f <- function(x, y) x^2 + y
x <- runif(30)
y <- runif(30)
z <- f(x, y) + rnorm(30, sd = 0.2)
plot3d(x, y, z)
plot3d(f, add = TRUE, col = "gray")
```

After some fiddling with the view, you get this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for